# creating an array of objects with values place by user in Java

Tags: java

So Basically, I'm currently having a problem with my program, where I would like to create an array list of objects and have the values placed by the user, I've yet to go about how to doing that.

In my main class, I've created these attributes.

```
List<Games> games = new ArrayList<Games>();
    List<Company> company = new ArrayList<Company>();
    int userchoice;
```

And in the games.java class I used similar attributes for receiving data.

games.java

```
public List<Games> getTitles() {
    return titles;
}


public void setTitles(List<Games> titles) {
    this.titles = titles;
}
```

I would use `games.add(gameTitle);` to place values, but it would give me 2 errors.

One of them would tell me that `incompatible types: String cannot be converted into Games` when I use the `games.add(1, gamesTitle);`

The next would tell me

```
method collection.Add(Games) is not applicable, String cannot be converted to Games.
```

What I'm trying to do is to get the user values from gameID and game Title, into an arrayList that will then send that data to classes as arguments and place them into a database.

This is a Java Persistence API project I'm working on and any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Games.java Class

```
@Entity (name = "Games")
public class Games implements Serializable {
@Id 
private int id;
private String title;
private String genre;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="GamesComp")

private Company comp_Name;


public int getId() {
    return id;
}


public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}


public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}


public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}


public String getGenre() {
    return genre;
}


public void setGenre(String genre) {
    this.genre = genre;
}


public Company getComp_Name() {
    return comp_Name;
}


public void setComp_Name(Company comp_Name) {
    this.comp_Name = comp_Name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Game ID: " + getId() + " Title: " + getTitle() + 
           " with " + getGenre();
}
```

Company Class

```
@Entity
@Table (name="Company")
public class Company implements Serializable {
@Id 
private int id;
private String compName;
@OneToMany(cascade = ALL, mappedBy="comp")   

private List<Games> titles;

public Company() {
    titles = new ArrayList<>();
}


public int getId() {
    return id;
}


public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}


public String getCompName() {
    return compName;
}


public void setCompName(String compName) {
    this.compName = compName;
}

public void addGameTitles(Games t) {
    this.titles.add(t);
    t.setComp_Name(this);

}


public List<Games> getTitles() {
    return titles;
}


public void setTitles(List<Games> titles) {
    this.titles = titles;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Company ID: " + getId() + 
           ", Company Name: " + getCompName();
}
```

Comment: can you pleas add a little bit more code, we need to see what are you doing there... do you have a class Games dont you??

Comment: I can add it now for you

Comment: I also have a company class which takes values from the arraylist of games

Answer (score 0):

The issue is: you are trying to insert an string object into a List of Games Objects...

replace this `List<Games> games = new ArrayList<Games>();`

for this:

```
List<String> games = new ArrayList<String>();
```

you could of course define the **Games** Class like

```
class Games{
...
Games(String gameTitle){
}
```

and some where in the code add games to the list of games:

```
games.add(new Games("CallOfDuty"));
```

imho, the last option is more elegant and reflects a better design  model..

but you have the freedom of choice.